# Display data from other site in my app

Tags: android, web

I'm new to programming and I would like to display data from this site into my activity. Simple textviews with name and numbers nothing more. The problem is I don't know how to get those info from this site. When I open it with Firefox and try to inspect code, I can't find any variables from which it could be read, if I'm saying this correct!? :)

Can someone point me to right direction???
This is the web page: 
http://parking-servis.co.rs/eng/where-to-park/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the other user mentioned this is too broad, but I can give you a few pointers and things you can start reading up on.

First: You want to get info from a website.
This can be easily done via web scraping. What this means is you read through the HTML code of a webpage and extract information from it. Libraries such as `Jsoup` will help you a lot here. They have great documentation so that should get you going. You can just hover over any HTML element to get its related information when the element is highlighted.

Second:You need to get this information to your App.
Well you are in luck because Jsoup has its own android port and you can simply import the library to your project and go ahead from there. You can write a simple flow that scrapes the website every day or e erytime the app is opened. You can pass net requests via something called `AsysncTask`.

So the library to start looking into is [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download) and you should also read up on [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). Besides these, there are other links you might be interested in :

[Web Parsing with JSoup](https://medium.com/@werdna3232/how-to-use-jsoup-to-scrape-webpages-tutorial-d0a676661b4a)

[JSoup on Android](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f)

[AsyncTask Basic Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial)

Comment: OK, thx, I will look into that. Also, if I use webview in my activity to just represent that table of contents that I need, is it possible to ignore all the rest on that page and just show that table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complicated task, if the website doesn't provide an API you will have to web scrape to get the information off of that page. as for getting the data into android studio you will have to research how to use GET / POST calls to (hopefully) an API with that information.

Not much else I can do as this question is very broad, but hope it has helped.

Comment: OK, thx for the answer. Like I wrote in a comment above, if I use webview in my activity to just represent that table of contents that I need, is it possible to ignore all the rest on that page and just show that table?